# .FOUR command doesn't give the required output

Tags: ltspice, pspice, fourier

This netlist for a full wave rectifier was actually written for PSPICE. When I type the same netlist in LTSpiceXVII, the log file doesn't show the proper output. I have replaced `ITL5=0` by `ITL6=0` in my netlist.

**netlist:**

full wave rectifier

```
VS 1 0 SIN(0 169.7V 60HZ)

LE 3 8 30.83MH

CE 7 4 326UF

RX 8 7 80M

L 5 6 10MH

R 7 5 40

VX 6 4 DC 0V

VY 1 2 DC 0V

D1 2 3 DMOD

D2 4 0 DMOD

D3 0 3 DMOD

D4 4 2 DMOD

.MODEL DMOD D (IS=2.22E-15 BV=1800V)

.TRAN 10US 50MS 33MS 50US

.FOUR 120HZ V(6,5)

.options ITL6=0 abstol=1.000u reltol=.05 vntol=0.01m plotwinsize=0

.END
```

**The log file is not showing the proper output:**
[image: log file]

Why isn't the same code working for LTSpiceXVII?

This is the circuit diagram

[image: ckt diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LTspice doesn't like not having any grounds anywhere.
Try this.

[image]

```
* C:\Users\pat\Desktop\Draft1.asc
VS1 vi1 vi2 SINE(0 169.7 60)
D1 vi1 3 D
D4 0 vi1 D
D2 0 vi2 D
D3 vi2 3 D
LE1 8 3 30.83mH
RX1 7 8 80m
CE1 7 0 326µ
R1 7 5 40
L1 5 6 10mH
VX1 6 0 0
.model D D
.lib C:\Users\pat\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.dio
.MODEL DMOD D (IS=2.22e-15 BV=1800V)
.TRAN 10us 50ms 33ms 50us
.FOUR 120Hz V(5)-V(6)
.options ITL6=0 abstol=1.000u reltol=.05 vntol=0.01m plotwinsize=0
.backanno
.end
```

Comment: OP's netlist has ground.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen If the OP's ground is in his original position, then high-value resistors need to be added from nodes 4 & 3 to ground to appease LTspice.

Comment: @qrk ... or add `Rs` and `Cjo` in the `.MODEL` definition, as in my answer. IMHO that's a better solution because it takes care of other, possible issues further down the road, though I'm not dismissing this one, either.

Answer (score 1):

The defaults for the diode `.MODEL` are, mostly, zero, including `Rs` and parasitic capacitances. By using only `Is` and `Bv` you are using a diode with zero resistance, and that may (and can, in this case) cause convergence issues. If you'll add `Rs=1m Cjo=10p` to the `.MODEL` definition you'll see that it works. Part of the issues arise from having the ground on the source side, as opposed to the load side -- if you switch the node `4` with the ground you won't even need to add `Rs` and `Cjo`.

BTW, the first value of `10u` in the `.TRAN` card is pretty pointless, you could keep it zero. Its meaning is 40+ years old and only used for backward compatibility in `.TRAN` commands, but it's ignored nowadays. The 4th argument is the one that sets the timestep.

Why are you tormenting yourself with a netlist instead of a graphical schematic?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **title** in line 1. The definition of VS is used as a title, not a voltage source. Add something like `* My Circuit` as line 1. This is standard SPICE syntax which LTspice adheres to.

Showing a schematic of your circuit is also helpful.

Comment: I've actually left a blank space as line 1 but even adding the title gives the same output.

Comment: @p_p Graph various nodes in your circuit (Ctrl+A in the graph plane). A good starting point is V(1). From there you may be able to debug what's happening. Not having a schematic makes troubleshooting difficult for people on this forum.